# BB and Crank compatibility with Pressfit 86.5

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, sram

The bike frame I'm buying says that It is Pressfit BB86.5 (road), What are my options in terms of bottom brackets and cranks? I would like to get a BB30 Sram Force crank is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Pressfit 86.5 is really PF86.

As outlined in this [BikeRadar guide](http://www.bikeradar.com/us/gear/article/complete-guide-to-bottom-brackets-36660/) (or this from [Problem Solvers](http://problemsolversbike.com/files/tech/Bottom_Bracket_Standards_Reference.pdf)), your crank options are: "Standard 24mm external-type (Shimano Hollowtech II, SRAM/Truvativ GXP, Campagnolo Ultra-Torque, FSA MegaExo, Race Face X-Type, etc), BB386 EVO".

The bottom bracket options are corresponding BB86 sized options.

You can't use a BB30 crankset/BB.

Answer (score 2):

As Batman has said already and linked to the guide the pf86 is a 24mm axle standard.

You can buy flanged bearings that allow you to run some 30mm cranks with a spindle length longer than 104mm (I don't know if this means you could run your SRAM crank with a 104mm spindle!). [Wheels Mfg](http://wheelsmfg.com/bb86-to-30mm-sealed-bearing.html)make them.

[image]

I guess it's about whether you want to run a non-standard system. I've always believed (with no evidence to back this up at all) that you lose reliability and longevity once off the standard.

Comment: Rotor's PF4130 is a similar part, but the spindle length is the key part which most BB30 cranksets won't have.